# Recurring function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I have a function that checks if a number is divisible by 2.5, if it isn't it adds 0.5 then calls itself again with the new value. It returns undefined when I call it like below but if I `console.log` instead of `return`inside the function then the correct rounded up value displays.

```
function n(num){
    if(num % 2.5 === 0){
        return num;
    }else{
        num += 0.5;
        n(num)  
    }
}

console.log(n(13.5))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to return the recursive call so that your conditions will be checked again until your if condition is satisfied:

```
function n(num){
    if(num % 2.5 === 0){
        return num;
    }else{
        num += 0.5;
        return n(num); //<-- add return
    }
}

console.log(n(13.5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes because the second `n(num)` call is not returning anything to the original caller.

Make it:

```
    else{
        num += 0.5;
        return n(num);
    }
```